# Best Ways to Achieve this organic look?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Specifically the holes in the mesh. Not sure the best way to approach this. I've tested using a Voronoi Texture with Displacement but to even get a somewhat similar design the polycount becomes too extreme.

Any Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: don't you want to simply fake it with a Bump node?

Comment: i would prefer real geometry, don't think I'll get the depth i am looking for with just a Bump

Answer (score 28):

So many ways to go about it that it's hard to give a definitive answer, but here are some methods and resources you might wanna look at:

1. Just trial and error with various modifiers. Here's the default monkey with some modifiers on it I just put together in about 45 seconds:

[image]

2. [The *Tissue* add-on (free).](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue) It can look intimidating at first, but it's actually relatively straightforward and really flexible and powerful once you learn it. It comes with Blender already, but the Github version is usually a little ahead in terms of updates. [The documentation](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue/wiki/Tessellate) is very helpful.

[image]

3. Geometry Nodes. Not entirely different from using modifiers, or *Tissue*, but it can be more performant and flexible, not to mention future-proof, than both. The example below is from [Benny Govaert's Twitter](https://twitter.com/bennygovaerts/status/1494661798880063492). There's a [YouTube video by Jimmy Gunawan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3StvubCgJ-k) which takes that node setup from Twitter to recreate and expand upon it. It mostly revolves around the *Dual Mesh* node, which is also a feature in *Tissue*.

[image]

4. [BY-GEN add-on (free, with some paid presets).](https://curtisholt.online/by-gen)

Answer (score 12):

In order to keep a rather low-polygon mesh, you could create an icosphere, bevel all in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Select one of the resulting hexagons, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (Select Similar) > *Polygon Sides* and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

*Shade Smooth* your object, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

In *Sculpt* mode, deform it with the *Grab* brush and others:

[image]

From Kuboå's answer I realize that you may need hollow holes, in that case remove the hexagons, give your object a *Solidify* before the *Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

Then deform:

[image]